# Different results whenever i run this program concurrently using mutex

Tags: c, mutex

I am writting a program which computes the value of pi using the bailey-borwein-plouffe formula.My problem is i keep getting different results whenever i run this code using the mutex.I am not sure if the mutex lock in the pie function definition should be used for just one resource pi .

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     1000

void *pie_function(void * p);//returns the value of pie
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //creates a mutex variable
double pi=0,p16=1;
 main()
{
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];  //creates the number of threads using NUM_THREADS
int iret1;   //used to ensure that threads are created properly
         //pthread_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg)

int i;
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);


for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
      iret1= pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,pie_function,(void *) i);
   if(iret1){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", iret1);
        exit(-1);
   }

}

for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
  iret1=pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);

 if(iret1){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", iret1);
        exit(-1);
   }
```

}

```
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
  printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
  printf("The value of pi is  : %f\n",pi);

  exit(0);

   }



 void *pie_function(void *s){
 int rc;
 int k=(int) s;
  pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 ); //locks the share variable pi and p16
   pi += 1.0/p16 * (4.0/(8*k + 1) - 2.0/(8*k + 4) - 1.0/(8*k + 5) - 1.0/(8*k+6));
 p16 *=16;

 rc=pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
 if(rc){
    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);
  }



  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off ditching threads totally in this case.

Threading is handy when a group of threads can execute mostly in their own little world without affecting each other (occasional resource contention is okay).

However, since your threads are very short-lived and pretty well lock the mutex for their entire lifetime, you are getting no advantage from threading. All you're doing is adding extra overhead for little or no benefit.

This particular task would be better handled a a series of sequential steps.

---

However, if you feel you *must* do this thing, you can fix the problem by looking at the following formula:

```
pi += 1.0/p16 * (4.0/(8*k + 1) - 2.0/(8*k + 4) - 1.0/(8*k + 5) - 1.0/(8*k+6));
```

Obviously, what gets added to `pi` depends on both `k` and `p16`. Now your `p16` is well-controlled (within the mutex) but your `k` is not since it's passed in as a parameter.

The problem you have is that, even though you may start the thread with `k == 7` before the one with `k == 8`, there's no guarantee that the former will get the mutex first. If the latter gets the mutex first, your `k` and `p16` will not have "compatible" values. Such are the vagaries of threading.

You can fix this by putting `k` under the control of the mutex.

In other words, don't pass it as a parameter, rather do the same thing as you do with `p16`. Initialise them all with:

```
double pi=0, p16=1;
int k = 0;
```

Then have your thread function contain:

```
// Should actually check all mutex calls.

pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex1);
pi += 1.0/p16 * (4.0/(8*k + 1) - 2.0/(8*k + 4) - 1.0/(8*k + 5) - 1.0/(8*k+6));
p16 *=16;
k++;
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);
```

This way, the values of `k` and `p16` are kept in step regardless of the order of thread execution.

However, I still maintain that threads are a bad idea in this case.

Comment: You are absolutely right.I just want to implement this using threads and see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @user1850254, what you're doing wrong (if threading is needed) is assuming that the threads do their work with sequential values of `k` (see the answer by user315052). My contention is that threads are a bad idea in this use case. If you want to learn threading, at least choose a suitable area of endeavour :-)

Comment: @Would changing the formula used to calculate pi help?

Comment: @user1850254, no, not the formula itself, just the way you keep the variables in sync - see the update.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I provided a suggestion in my answer that would be a better use of threads.

Comment: @paxdiablo That explains it well.I just have to go and think more about it.Thank you.Would you have any resource/examples  to point me to?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `s` is incorrect. The power applied to `p16` should match `k`, but you are using sequential powers of `p16` to randomly selected `k`. This is according to [the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) I found.

The reason why `k` is randomly selected is because you have no control over the order of the threads once they are started.

So this line:

```
int k = (int)s;
```

Sets `k` to the value of passed in to the thread. But which value `k` gets set to depends on the order the threads get executed.

You will only get the right answer if the thread with `s == 0` gets to go first, and if the thread with `s == n+1` always gets to go after the thread with `s == n`.

*This is my last edit:* One way to fix the program other than ditching threads altogether is to separate out the sums so that each thread is computing part of the answer, and the right answer is obtained by adding together each thread's partial sum. For example, you could have 4 threads, where each thread starts from `i = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }`, and each computes the sum of every fourth term offset from their initial term. The stopping condition for the summation would be when the computed term falls below some threshold. So, the `pie_function` could be implemented like this:

```
const double THRESH = 0.0000001;
int k = (int)s;
double p16 = pow(16, k);
double p16_4 = pow(16, 4);
double subpi = 0;
for (;;) {
    double k8 = 8*k;
    double term = 1/p16 * (4/(k8+1) - 2/(k8+4) - 1/(k8+5) - 1/(k8+6));
    if (term < THRESH) break;
    subpi += term;
    k += 4;
    p16 *= p16_4;
} 
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
pi += subpi;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
return 0;
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.K is an internal variable which is gotten from casting s to an int.my values range from 3.141591 t0 0.238109

Comment: But it shouldnt matter i guess since each thread would work on its own k and add it to the sum.e.g if there are 4 threads,thread 1 might get number 3,thread 2 number 1,thread 3 number 4,thread 4 number 3.It should still work our because i am getting the total sum.

Comment: @user1850254: The formula gets applied wrong. Assume 2 threads. See if you get the same answer when you change the order the threads go.

Comment: @You are right.I thought it didn't matter what order the s(k) is being passed into th funtion.What would you do to make this program work or you can point me in the right direction of how to fix it.

Comment: @user1850254: I created a suggestion in my answer.